# Python script that runs in Windows throws "<string>" error in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 18.04, scripts, python

I've written a Python script (work.py) and it's running well in Windows, but when I run it on Ubuntu, it shows me an error, if I enter the name as a **string**, but if I enter the name as an **integer** it's running fine.

NameError:

```
thanapong@thanapong-Lenovo-C360:~/Desktop$ python work.py 
Hours: 72 
Minutes: 0 
Seconds: 0 
Enter the name: CHATCHAI 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "work.py", line 9, in <module>
    look for = str(input("Enter the name: "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
NameError: name 'CHATCHAI' is not defined 
thanapong@thanapong-Lenovo-C360:~/Desktop$ python work.py 
Hours: 72 
Minutes: 0 
Seconds: 0 
Enter the name: BILLY 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "work.py", line 9, in <module>
    look for = input("Enter the name: ") 
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
NameError: name 'BILLY' is not defined
```

With int it works fine:

```
thanapong@thanapong-Lenovo-C360:~/Desktop$ python work.py 
Hours: 72 
Minutes: 0 
Seconds: 0 
Enter the name: 2

3
0
Not found
1
2
3
4
0
Not found
1
2
3
4
0
Not found
1
2
```

This is my code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import time

hourz=input('Hours: ')
minz=input('Minutes: ')
secz=input('Seconds: ')
lookfor = input("Enter the name: ")
name = str(lookfor)
x = 5
print(' ')
hour=int(hourz)
min=int(minz)
sec=int(secz)
day = int(((hour*60*60)+(min*60)+(sec))/86400)

print(day)
for b in range(day):
    for a in range(x):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(a)
        if a == 0:
            data = pd.read_csv("/media/thanapong/F91B-8B18/Customer_List.txt", header=0)
            query = data.loc[data['NAME']==name]
            if not query.empty:
                print(query)
                data.loc[data['NAME']==name, 'SCORE'] = (query.SCORE - 1)
                print()
                print(data.loc[data['NAME']==name])
                data.to_csv("/media/thanapong/F91B-8B18/Customer_List.txt", index=None)
            else:
                print('Not found')
print(' ')
print(' ')                
print("End")
```

This is example of Customer_List.txt (it has many lines).

```
ID,NAME,LASTNAME,SCORE,TEL,PASS
61070500216,CHATCHAI,KARUNA,22,123456789,12345
61070500217,BIGM,KORATBOY,15,123456789,123456789
```

Comment: For python2, you need to use `raw_input()` I think. Perhaps your default python on Windows is python3? See for example [Python Input and Output](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/python/getting-started/input-and-output/tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you so much.it's run now.

Comment: Related: [Why is Python 2.7 still the default Python version in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165360/why-is-python-2-7-still-the-default-python-version-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 4):

So far, in Ubuntu, a `python` command provided by the system is always Python 2, never Python 3, and for Python 3 one must use `python3`.

This is the case even on systems that don't have Python 2 installed but have Python 3 installed. Newer Ubuntu releases come that way, and there is a `python3` command but no `python` command. You can install the `python` metapackage, which installs Python 2.

Older Ubuntu releases ship with Python 2 installed and not Python 3. As [Raffa says](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164617/22949), you can install Python 3 on such a system through the `python3` metapackage.

Until recently, having `python` be Python 2 (and not Python 3) [had been the official recommendation for Unix-like operating systems](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/#history-of-this-pep). The popular GNU/Linux systems adhered to this recommendation, with the notable exception of Arch Linux and its derivatives, on which `python` has long been Python 3. Debian and Ubuntu (which is a derivative of Debian), among other systems, continue to use the traditionally recommended naming scheme, so far.

In my experience, users of some other OSes--especially Windows--often find this surprising. It can be especially confusing to novices who aren't well aware of the distinction between Python 2 and Python 3.

My recommendation is:

1. Always know (or find out) which of Python 2 or Python 3 one is writing.

   It is possible to write code deliberately that works as both, but people who do that know they're doing it, and this is not something most people will do when they start out.
2. For Python source code files that you run (i.e., scripts/programs, rather than modules usable only as libraries), start the file with a shebang line that specifies which interpreter you want.

   For Python 3 you will usually wanted to use `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, as [Ray Butterworth](https://askubuntu.com/users/908977/ray-butterworth) has [commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164607/python-file-string-error#comment1941194_1164617). For Python 2, consider `#!/usr/bin/env python2`. Although you *can* use `#!/usr/bin/env python` in Ubuntu, 
   using the `python2` command is also supported, makes your meaning clear to humans, works on more operating systems, and might work longer into the future.

The shebang line doesn't affect what interpreter is used if you run the script by passing its name as an argument to a command like `python` (or `python2`) or `python3`. Instead, mark the script executable so you can run it:

```
chmod +x scriptname
```

You only have to do that once. Then you can run the script like this:

```
./scriptname
```

On Windows, you can use the `py` launcher command to run your script, which respects your shebang line unless you override it by specifying a version. That is, if your script starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python2`, running `py scriptname` in Windows has the same effect as `py -2 scriptname`, and if it starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, running `py scriptname` in Windows has the same effect as `py -3 scriptname`.

Note, however, that `py` treats `python` (with no version number) as specifying Python 3 rather than Python 2. This is another reason to consider writing `python2` (rather than just `python`) at the end if your shebang lines even in Ubuntu; it makes your scripts more portable to Windows when the `py` launcher is used.

---

As for why you got *those* errors when you inadvertently ran your Python 3 code in a Python 2 interpreter: the [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function in Python 3 just reads and returns a line of input, which is what you want, but the [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) function in Python 2 [reads a line of input, *treats it as Python code, runs that code, and returns the resulting value*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40604113/what-was-the-rationale-behind-creating-input-in-python-2). This has [quite alarming security implications](https://snyk.io/blog/python-2-vs-3-security-differences/#input-method) when used without care ([even in Python 2 programs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12169487/1038860)), and is also just [not something people usually want to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960208/python-2-7-getting-user-input-and-manipulating-as-string-without-quotations). If you needed to write your script in Python 2, you would use the [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) function instead [as steeldriver says](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164607/python-script-that-runs-in-windows-throws-string-error-in-ubuntu/1164771#comment1941178_1164607), but really the solution is to use [`python3`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/python3.1.html) as described above, which [in spite of its name is effectively the default Python interpreter in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165365/22949). Inputs like `123` are Python expressions, but inputs like `BILLY` aren't, unless some variable by that name has been defined; this is why numerical input happened to work.

Comment: This answer makes its question more or less canonical at Ask Ubuntu. I searched Ask Ubuntu for a decent explanation of the topic in the question and didn't find it except for here.

Comment: This answer is very informative, useful, well thought and complete.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and it executed correctly. I could not create the same error as in your image. Your code accepted a string as an input for the name field. Python version 3.7 and operating system Ubuntu. Please see the output below:

```
Hours: 72
Minutes: 0
Seconds: 0
Enter the name: BILLY

3
0
   ID   NAME  LASTNAME  SCORE  ...  KORATBOY  15  123456789.1  123456789.2
0 NaN  BILLY       NaN    NaN  ...       NaN NaN          NaN          NaN

[1 rows x 16 columns]

   ID   NAME  LASTNAME  SCORE  ...  KORATBOY  15  123456789.1  123456789.2
0 NaN  BILLY       NaN    NaN  ...       NaN NaN          NaN          NaN

[1 rows x 16 columns]
1
2
3
4
0
   ID   NAME  LASTNAME  SCORE  ...  KORATBOY  15  123456789.1  123456789.2
0 NaN  BILLY       NaN    NaN  ...       NaN NaN          NaN          NaN

[1 rows x 16 columns]

   ID   NAME  LASTNAME  SCORE  ...  KORATBOY  15  123456789.1  123456789.2
0 NaN  BILLY       NaN    NaN  ...       NaN NaN          NaN          NaN

[1 rows x 16 columns]
1
2
3
4
0
   ID   NAME  LASTNAME  SCORE  ...  KORATBOY  15  123456789.1  123456789.2
0 NaN  BILLY       NaN    NaN  ...       NaN NaN          NaN          NaN

[1 rows x 16 columns]

   ID   NAME  LASTNAME  SCORE  ...  KORATBOY  15  123456789.1  123456789.2
0 NaN  BILLY       NaN    NaN  ...       NaN NaN          NaN          NaN

[1 rows x 16 columns]
1
2
3
4


End

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I think the solution is you need to use `python3` at the command prompt and **NOT** `python` to run your file. Your code is clearly written for `python3`

If python3 is not installed on your system, you can install it by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install python3
```

Comment: The script will also need this first line:  ``#!/usr/bin/env python3`` to ensure it gets the correct one.