# Visual Studio Code shows invalid syntax for "end" parameter in print()

Tags: command-line, python, python3, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run this Python program with Visual Studio Code:

```py
# This Python program must be run with
# Python 3 as it won't work with 2.7.

# ends the output with a <space>
print("Welcome to" , end = ' ')
print("GeeksforGeeks", end = ' ')
```

But while building I get following output and error messages in console:

```py
$ python /home/mrrobot/Documents/Python/loop_while.py
  File "/home/mrrobot/Documents/Python/loop_while.py", line 5
    print("Welcome to" , end = ' ')
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What could be the problem here? How can I fix it?

[image: screenshot of VS Code]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python script that runs in Windows throws "<string>" error in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1164607) The specific error is different but the situation is pretty much the same. As the comments in the code say, the code is Python 3 and it does not work when run with a Python 2 interpreter. VS Code shows what interpreter you're using on the lower left of the window as Python 2. Furthermore, you're using [the `python` command, which in Ubuntu is still nearly always Python 2](https://askubuntu.com/q/1165360). Use `python3` instead and the program should work.

Answer (score 1):

As @Eliah Kagan pointed out, the error occurs because your VS Code is using Python 2 as the interpreter. [Switch to Python 3 interpreter in your VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) and it should work.

P.S. Free PEP style tip: Write `print('something', end=' ')`. When giving default values to parameters, avoid spacing around the `=` operator.