# My default python version is 2.7.18rc1 after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, python, 20.04

We knew Ubuntu 20.04 will set python 3 as default python, but after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04, I found my default python version is 2.7.18rc1 not python3:

[image: my system version and python version]

Comment: This is a known issue. See: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/04/whats-new-in-ubuntu-2004-lts-focal.html `Further more, /usr/bin/python is not present on new Ubuntu 20.04 installs (for upgraded systems, /usr/bin/python continues to point to python2). If you need /usr/bin/python to point to python3, install the python-is-python3 package.`

Comment: There is currently no plan to make `python` point to `python3`. That would break a lot of legacy homemade python2 scripts still floating around on folks' systems, and would confuse a lot of folks needlessly.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165360/

Comment: @karel the duplicate question does say "But I still have it. Why is that?" and then runs the python command to show what they're talking about. Look beyond the title into the actual question.

$ python
Python 2.7.18rc1

Comment: In this question the OP wants to know what to do with the `python` command either to start the system default Python 3 interpreter or how to start the system default Python 3 interpreter with a different command (a command different from `python`) in order to be able to use Python 2 alongside Python 3. Let's assume that the OP in this question already knows that Python 2 is still supported in 20.04 from his own screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Running the `python` command in the terminal starts the Python 2 interpreter if Python 2 is installed, as it is in your Ubuntu 20.04. In Ubuntu 20.04 you can also start Python 3 which is preinstalled with the `python` command by installing the *python-is-python3* package.

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

You can also start the Python 3 interpreter from the terminal the usual way by running `python3`

Comment: root@debian:~# apt install python-is-python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-is-python3

Comment: Results of `apt policy python-is-python3` :  `python-is-python3: Installed: (none) Candidate: 3.8.2-4 Version table: 3.8.2-4 500 500 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from a solution with installing **python-is-python3** (mentioned in comment by Stephan Boston), there's one more  using **update-alternatives** or using GUI **galternatives**, which would work not only with python, but any tool and any number of its versions.

Let's start at the very beginning. I have newly installed Ubuntu 20.04 and in */usr/bin* don't even have sole **python**, but only **python3** and **python2**.
You type:

```
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 9
# update-alternatives --config python
```

After typing the last command you would be asked to choose the prefered version manually or leave the selection in auto mode, where in our example python3 has higher priority 10 than 9 of python2, so python3 would be default.

```
 Selection    Path               Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3   10        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2   9         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3   10        manual mode
```

If I've typped **1**:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.18rc1
```

I've changed my mind and in *update-alternatives --config python* selected **0** for auto (bidding for the highest priority):

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.2
```