# I can't check Python version on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, python, 20.04, python3

I was trying to check the Python version on my device. In the terminal I used the command `python --version`. But it outputs a message saying

```
Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

 command 'python3' from deb
 command 'python' from deb python-is-python3
```

I tried reinstalling Python 3. But it still shows the same thing. What should I do now?

Comment: `python3 --version` >> Python 3.8.2. If you like to run `python3` using `python` then install `python-is-python3` package.

Comment: `python` generally refers to Python 2 unless configured/specified. On releases > 18.04, Python 2 isn't installed by default since it's *dead*. 20.04 gives you an option to invoke Python 3 using `python` by merely installing a package.

Answer (score 3):

Up until Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, both python2 and python3 were preinstalled on Ubuntu. Since Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, things have changed. Python2 is not preinstalled. Only python3 (v3.8.2 in 20.04) is preinstalled. At this moment if you run `python3 --version`, you will see version 3.8.2 is installed. However if you have also installed python 2 (on your own, it is not preinstalled), then you can use `python2 --version` or `python --version` to check the version of python2.

To check info about python3, you will have to use `python3 --version` or something which starts with `python3` explicitly. Where as `python` and `python2` will refer python2.

**EDIT 1**
The reason they did this was because python2 itself has reached [EOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-life_(product)) (end of life).
Related news [article](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Python-2-EOL-Ubuntu-20.04).

**EDIT 2**
Python 2 has now been moved to from main repository to universe repository.

> The four main repositories are:
>
> ```
> Main - Canonical-supported free and open-source software.
>
> Universe - Community-maintained free and open-source software.
>
> Restricted - Proprietary drivers for devices.
>
> Multiverse - Software restricted by copyright or legal issues.
> ```

**EDIT 3**
To make `python` command to point to python3, install `python-is-python3` package by running `sudo apt install python-is-python3` command in terminal.

Comment: Python 2 was installed by default until **18.04**.

Comment: @Kulfy No, it was first removed in 20.04 LTS. Between 18.04 there were 19.10, 18.10 and 19.04. They had python2 installed in them out of the box. On google also it says that Ubuntu 20.04 was first to drop python2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165360/why-is-python-2-7-still-the-default-python-version-in-ubuntu in the given question, it was still installed on 19.04. If you still think I am wrong, pls provide me a proof, and I will update my answer. Because to my best knowledge, 20.04 was first to drop python2.

Comment: you should add @Ravexina comment to your answer.

Comment: @AbhayPatil For *proof*, see [release notes of 18.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes). Also, 18.04 was the last LTS release to have Python 2 in main repository. 20.04 has Python 2 in Universe repository. **P.S.** I'm the owner of the answer on the question you linked.

Comment: @bac0n pls suggest an edit and I will accept it

Comment: "using python then install python-is-python3 package. – Ravexina♦ 1 hour ago"