# I can't seem to figure out how to download the python shell

Tags: python

So, I have a book about Python, and it wants me to download the python shell from this website:
[www.python.org/downloads/source](http://www.python.org/downloads/source)

I can't figure out how. Can someone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't check Python version on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256996/i-cant-check-python-version-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: You haven't given your OS/release details, but older releases have `python3` and `python` (which means python2) pre-installed. Recent releases already have `python3` installed (the default now for `python`)   You should need to download or install anything for any supported release (or flavor) of Ubuntu

Comment: @guiverc did you want to say "... should **not** need to download..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 has Python 3 pre-installed.

To open the Python shell, from a terminal type:

```
python3
```

In other supported Ubuntu versions you can install Python from the repositories. I would suggest you do this rather than downloading installers from the Internet:

```
sudo apt install python3
```

Then run `python3` to open the Python shell.