# usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory # error while doing Sony AOSP project

Tags: python, android, sony

```
nik@nik-desktop:~/android$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-10.0.0_r41
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
nik@nik-desktop:~/android$
```

I am getting this error while initializing AOSP tree, please help me with this issue. I am trying to do Android 10 build for Sony XZS. I have already installed python.

Link of sony AOSP : https://developer.sony.com/develop/open-devices/guides/aosp-build-instructions/build-aosp-android-android-10-0-0

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your Ubuntu **version** and **how** you installed python

Comment: Related: [I can't check Python version on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256996/i-cant-check-python-version-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

issue is resolved now. it was a system path configuration issue. Just run these three cmd & you are good to go.

1: sudo apt update
2: sudo apt install python3
3: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python