# How to update system python 2.7 to 3.x in Ubuntu 20.x after upgrade

Tags: apt, 20.04, python3, python-2.7

I have an old VM that started out as Ubuntu 16.x then I upgraded it to the 18x series and now 20.x series. I was surprised that python 2.7 was still the system python.

I discovered that if you upgrade from 18x to 20x the system python is NOT changed.
[Why is Python 2.7 still the default Python version in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165360/why-is-python-2-7-still-the-default-python-version-in-ubuntu)
On fresh install of Ubuntu 20.x python 3.x is the default.

What is the correct procedure to remove python 2.7 from an upgraded system?

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1277240/edit) to show us the complete output of `which python` and `which python3`

Comment: My `python` switched from default in python2 to python3.  `python -V; python3 -V` now report the same version for both (I have to use `python2 -V` to get a python2 version.  Using normal upgrade procedures I'd expect to have `python` and `python3` both report the same, any failures are likely to be because of changes made by users, as clean systems (with any official packages added) will upgrade correctly I believe.  Revert any changes you've made to your default python, back to default Ubuntu, and the upgrade tools will work as tested & expected.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is strange that Ubuntu still supports python2. I've had that problem on a brand new Ubuntu 20.04 with a python3 app that had `/usr/env/python` in its header.

Installing `sudo apt install python-is-python3`solved the issue.

**But don`t uninstall python2. Some scripts still might use it!**

Python2 is dead. I loved it, but times changes. So @LinuxSurfaceNut pointed into the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

Python alone will run python v2, to run Python 3 do the following:

```
python3 -V
```

If you get nothing try upgrading:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y upgrade
```

Then install pip

```
sudo apt install -y python3-pip
```

Then check version again

```
python3 -V
```

If you want python to run Python 3, you can do that using this guide: [How to make 'python' program command execute Python 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3)