# youtube-dl /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory

Tags: python, 20.04, youtube-dl

In Ubuntu 20.04, we get the following error:

```
❯ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

❯ youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4mihzeFqGA
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Ubuntu 20.04, `python3` is the installed default. The `python` variable is not set:

```
❯ which python
python not found
```

We can get around this by using `python3` and `which`:

```
❯ python3 $(which youtube-dl) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IE-CXNs6Sw
[youtube] 0IE-CXNs6Sw: Downloading webpage
```

Answer (score 8):

I think python is missing on your system so,

First of all check if you have python installed .
To check this simply open terminal and type `python`. If it shows python version and prompt then quit by typing  `quit()`

And if python is missing then install it with this command :

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

If that does not help, then try this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install  /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1000
```

Comment: Do this : sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1000

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to deal with this in Ubuntu 20.04+ is to symlink python to python3:

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

Note, however, that if you install other Python programs that rely on the older version of Python, they may not run or work correctly until you remove the symlink and install the older version of Python, or fix the programs to use Python 3.  But the older Python version is no longer supported, so it would be better to use only Python programs that can run under Python 3 in the first place.

Comment: or add `alias python=python3` to your bashrc

Comment: For other macOS users out there who found this: `/usr/bin/` is protected by [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899). However, you can still do the following command:`ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem trying to install youtube-dl in ubuntu 20.04 and spent a long time trying to resolve. On the verge of giving up, I saw this from Canonical and thought it looks too simple but tried it anyway! Problem solved!

`sudo snap install youtube-dl`

Comment: The nice thing about this solution is that after, you can still use the previous syntax    <youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1234567890>

Comment: This didn't work for me under Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa. I get the OPs message:

/usr/bin/env: «python»: No existe el archivo o el directorio

Answer (score 2):

This works for ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
nano $(which youtube-dl)
```

and then replace the first line (the shebang line i.e. #!...) with

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: this is a clean solution, nice

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need python 2 and only need python 3, the easiest is to just

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

It's actually just a symlink. The package description explains it:

> In Ubuntu, all python packages use explicit python3 or python2 interpreter
> and do not use unversioned `/usr/bin/python` at all. Some third-party code
> is now predominantly python3 based, yet may use `/usr/bin/python`.
>
> This is a convenience package which ships a symlink to point the
> `/usr/bin/python` interpreter at the current default `python3`. It may improve
> compatibility with other modern systems, whilst breaking some obsolete or
> 3rd-party software.

Answer (score 1):

The `python` variable is not set and `update-alternatives` will not work either. Let's fix that.

Afterwards, we can decide which version `python` points to using `$ sudo update-alternatives --config python`.

### Install alternatives for python 2 and 3

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 2

$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 3

$ sudo update-alternatives --list python
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python3
```

### Change which version to use (v3 default since higher priority)

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python

There are 2 choices for the alternative python (providing /usr/bin/python).

  Selection    Path              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3   3         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python2   2         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3   3         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:

$ python --version
Python 3.8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

#Debian 11
#Install

sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/bin/youtube-d

youtube-dl -U

/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory

**sudo ln -s  /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python**

youtube-dl -U

youtube-dl is up-to-date (2021.12.17)